# How to validate the second character is not "*"?

Tags: regex

I've been building this regex and it's getting complicated.

```
^(?=.{2,})[a-zA-Z0-9\s\-\,\.]+\*?$
```

Basically I validate names with it. But now I need to make sure it's a minimum of 2 characters but the first two are not "*".

Any idea?

Comment: `the first two are not "*"` - Does this mean that neither of the first two characters can be `*`? Or that one of then can be, but not both?

Comment: The first character can never be a star in your regular expression, because the first character must be in `[a-zA-Z0-9\s,.-]`. What exactly do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your lookahead to look for any characters apart from stars.

```
^(?=[^*]{2})
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have now is this

```
^(?=.{2,})[a-zA-Z0-9\s\-\,\.]+\*?$

or

^[a-zA-Z0-9\s,.-](?:[*]|[a-zA-Z0-9\s,.-]+[*]?)$

or

/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s,.-][*]$/ || /^[a-zA-Z0-9\s,.-]{2,}[*]?)$/
```

None allow * in the first character.

If you don't want * in the second character as well, you can do what
Mark suggests with the negative class in the lookahead or you can do it
without lookahead.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\s,.-]{2,}[*]?$
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand the question properly, but

```
^[^*][^*]
```

will only match string where neither of the first two characters are `*`. This matches `ab`, but not `a*`, `*b` or `**`.

If the requirement is that the string doesn't start with `**`, then just using the string manipulation operations built into whatever language you are using might be both simpler and faster. E.g. in python:

```
len(name) >= 2 and not name.startswith('**')
```

Or in C:

```
strlen(name) >= 2 && !(name[0] == '*' && name[1] == '*')
```